# node js DSE driver for Graph is not retrieving immediate data when one node is down

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise-graph

`var dse = require('dse-driver');
var cassaGraphClient = new dse.Client({
    contactPoints: config.cassandra.cassaClusterConf,
    profiles: [
        new dse.ExecutionProfile('default', {
            graphOptions: {
                name: config.cassandra.graphDB,
                readConsistency: dse.types.consistencies.quorum,
                writeConsistency: dse.types.consistencies.quorum
            },
            consistency :  dse.types.consistencies.quorum
        })
    ]
});`

- Total number of nodes : 6
- Replication factor : 3

One node is down and sometimes I am not able to get the Graph data immediately(before 1 -2 sec). Able to retrieve the data properly if I wait for few seconds (5-10 secs). My assumption is either I need to specify retry method or load balancing. But I don't find any example or proper documentation.

Thanks

Comment: You can look at the system logs to understand what is happening: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/troubleshooting-datastax-enterprise . You can also check the driver logs: https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-dse-driver#logging (you can filter out `verbose` level)

Answer (score 0):

How many data centers do you have?  If the 6 nodes are spread across 2 DCs, with quorum you could be doing full Cluster consistency checks.  You may want to try localquorum.  If that doesn't work, then you may want to look in your system.log to see if there are any other errors/warnings that can help you figure out the right path to solve this item.

Comment: Only one data center